# dealing with figures after appendices when writing elsarticle

Tags: appendices, elsarticle, document-configuration

I am writing a paper using elsarticle, in which I have to put all the figures individually in clear pages after the biblography and before the end of document. however since the I have appendices before the biblography part, all of the figures have the caption A.number, which indicates the figures related to appendix part. how can i distinguish between the figures of appendix and the main document in this case?